# Why is node exiting?

Tags: node.js

My node application is exiting and I am not sure why.  There are no event logs and the executable exits almost immediately. The node.js version is 0.10. We added logging and the process seems to be killed after 2 seconds and exits at different stages. How can we triage why this process is exiting?

Comment: Start here [Debugging Guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

If the application is exiting immediately without any logs/errors, be sure to check that the application is not missing the instruction to listen to requests on a port. As an example:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function(){
    console.log("listening port " + port);
});
```

8000 is a commonly used port during development, but you can change that value to a port that isn't used by the network/system as well as use environment variables to set the port.